# Returning HTML from class property in Python jinja2

Tags: python, html, jinja2

Good morning,

I have a class called **Banana**.

I've defined an @property **peel** which returns some HTML:

```
@property
def peel(self):
    return "<div>Here is a peel!</div>"
```

In my template, I am attempting to render this HTML:

```
<body>
    {{ banana.peel }}
</body>
```

However, it's getting decoded. The source ends up looking like:

```
&lt;div&gt;Here is a peel!&lt;div&gt;
```

I have read about *cgi.unescape*, but can't seem to import/use it in my HTML template.

I'm definitely new to Python, so any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`safe` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#builtin-filters):

```
{{ banana.peel | safe }}
```